# Millions of tiny matches in R : need performance

Tags: r, performance, join, position, match

I have a one million length vector of words called WORDS. I got a 9 millions objects list called SENTENCES. Each object of my list is a sentence which is represented by a 10-50 length vector of words. Here is an example :

```
head(WORDS)
[1] "aba" "accra" "ada" "afrika" "afrikan" "afula" "aggamemon"

SENTENCES[[1]]
[1] "how" "to" "interpret" "that" "picture"
```

I want to convert every sentence of my list into a numeric vector whose elements correspond to the position of the sentence's word in the WORDS big vector. 
Actually, I know how to do it with that command :

```
convert <- function(sentence){
  return(which(WORDS %in% sentence))
}

SENTENCES_NUM <- lapply(SENTENCES, convert)
```

The problem is that it takes way too long time. I mean my RStudio blows up although i got a 16Go RAM computer. So the question is do you have any ideas to speed up the computation?

Comment: Did you try it with `mclapply`?

Comment: Thkx, but no I'm on Windows an I got only one core

Comment: additionally have you tried `pmatch` instead of `which(..%in%..)` ?

Comment: Oh sorry I did not know about this Jaap. That's ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fastmatch, a small package by an R core person, hashes the lookups so the initial and especially subsequent searches are faster.

What you are really doing is making a factor with predefined levels common to each sentence. The slow step in his C code is sorting the factor levels, which you can avoid by providing the (unique) list of factor levels to his fast version of the factor function.

If you just want the integer positions, you can easily convert from factor to integer: many do this inadvertently.

You don't actually need a factor at all for what you want, just `match`. Your code also generates a logical vector, then recalculates positions from it: `match` just goes straight to the positions.

```
library(fastmatch)
library(microbenchmark)

WORDS <- read.table("https://dotnetperls-controls.googlecode.com/files/enable1.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[[1]]

words_factor <- as.factor(WORDS)

# generate 100 sentences of between 5 and 15 words:
SENTENCES <- lapply(c(1:100), sample, x = WORDS, size = sample(c(5:15), size = 1))

bench_fun <- function(fun)
  lapply(SENTENCES, fun)

# poster's slow solution:
hg_convert <- function(sentence)
  return(which(WORDS %in% sentence))

jw_convert_match <- function(sentence) 
  match(sentence, WORDS)

jw_convert_match_factor <- function(sentence) 
  match(sentence, words_factor)

jw_convert_fastmatch <- function(sentence) 
  fmatch(sentence, WORDS)

jw_convert_fastmatch_factor <- function(sentence)
  fmatch(sentence, words_factor)

message("starting benchmark one")
print(microbenchmark(bench_fun(hg_convert),
                     bench_fun(jw_convert_match),
                     bench_fun(jw_convert_match_factor),
                     bench_fun(jw_convert_fastmatch),
                     bench_fun(jw_convert_fastmatch_factor),
                     times = 10))

# now again with big samples
# generating the SENTENCES is quite slow...
SENTENCES <- lapply(c(1:1e6), sample, x = WORDS, size = sample(c(5:15), size = 1))
message("starting benchmark two, compare with factor vs vector of words")
print(microbenchmark(bench_fun(jw_convert_fastmatch),
                     bench_fun(jw_convert_fastmatch_factor),
                     times = 10))
```

I put this on https://gist.github.com/jackwasey/59848d84728c0f55ef11

The results don't format very well, suffice to say, fastmatch with or without factor input is dramatically faster.

```
# starting benchmark one
Unit: microseconds
                                   expr         min          lq         mean      median          uq         max neval
                  bench_fun(hg_convert)  665167.953  678451.008  704030.2427  691859.576  738071.699  777176.143    10
            bench_fun(jw_convert_match)  878269.025  950580.480  962171.6683  956413.486  990592.691 1014922.639    10
     bench_fun(jw_convert_match_factor) 1082116.859 1104331.677 1182310.1228 1184336.810 1198233.436 1436600.764    10
        bench_fun(jw_convert_fastmatch)     203.031     220.134     462.1246     289.647     305.070    2196.906    10
 bench_fun(jw_convert_fastmatch_factor)     251.474     300.729    1351.6974     317.439     362.127   10604.506    10

# starting benchmark two, compare with factor vs vector of words
Unit: seconds
                                   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
        bench_fun(jw_convert_fastmatch) 3.066001 3.134702 3.186347 3.177419 3.212144 3.351648    10
 bench_fun(jw_convert_fastmatch_factor) 3.012734 3.149879 3.281194 3.250365 3.498593 3.563907    10
```

And therefore I wouldn't go to the trouble of a parallel implementation just yet.

Comment: Oh thank you. Let us suppose that i just want to map worlds into integers whatever are those integers - Because actually, I don't care to use words positions to convert sentence into numeric vector, do you see something even easier?

Comment: I was assuming that you would want the same word to be represented by the same number in each sentence. If this is not the case, it does simplify the problem a little, but I doubt this is what you are after.

Comment: Even if you don't care about the order of words in each sentence, that is how they will be stored by R (because there is no equivalent to C++ `std::unsorted_set`).

Comment: Yeah sure, same word to the same integer. I've just tried it. That's really impressive. I really need to understand how you can improve from 700K seconds to 3 seconds!

Comment: I'm not a computer scientist, but have had to pick up a few performance tricks. Hashing, as simply as I understand it, is a way to derive the bucket containing a set element from the element itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table is a good place to start. The only thing I would add is that it is worth taking a look at source code, especially if something is slower than you need. You need to know exactly what the CPU is doing to the data in order to speed it up. In your case, it was shunting a huge amount of data from main memory to CPU every lookup, and this was likely the bottleneck

Comment: Oh Ok thanks. But when you say we have to know what the CPU is doing you think about the algorithm behind the function right? How do you know precisely what the CPU is doing, I don't get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91368/discussion-between-jack-wasey-and-hans-glick).

Answer (score -2):

Won't be faster, but it is the tidy way of going about things.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sentence = 
  data_frame(word.name = SENTENCES,
             sentence.ID = 1:length(SENTENCES) %>%
  unnest(word.name)

word = data_frame(
  word.name = WORDS,
  word.ID = 1:length(WORDS)

sentence__word = 
  sentence %>%
  left_join(word)
```